# White Box and Relative Positioning

Tags: positioning

I have to make a white box, blank of text, that is 1 by 1 inch and then position it exactly on the right side of the text. Also, I need to make the borders a bit thick.[image: coding result] How do I do this?

My coding is:

```
\section {Space Filling}
One inch away is a box which measures exactly 1" by 1":
\framebox
{ \begin{minipage}{1in} 
\hfill\vspace{1in}
\end{minipage} }
```

It should look like the image shown attached.

Comment: When you post a question and then get an answer, deleting that question is kind of insulting the person who tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

- The box can be moved by `\nobreak\hfill` or `\hspace*{\fill}` to the right side of the text area.
- `\raisebox{\depth}{...}` moves the box to the base line.
- The line width of `\fbox` can be controlled by `\fboxrule`.
- `\fboxsep` is used to create a white box with dimensions `2\fboxsep` × `2\fboxsep` (1in × 1in).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section {Space Filling}
One inch away is a box which measures 1" by 1":
\hspace*{\fill}
\raisebox{\depth}{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5in}%
  \fbox{}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the border should be included in the dimensions of 1in × 1in, then the border width needs to be subtracted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section {Space Filling}
One inch away is a box which measures 1" by 1":
\hspace*{\fill}
\raisebox{\depth}{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr.5in-\fboxrule\relax}%
  \fbox{}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question: how do you position the box left or right horizontally on that same line?

Comment: @user59223: `\hfill` or `\hspace*{\fill}` adds stretchable space to move the box to the right.

Comment: Got it. I used "\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}" to get what I want. I appreciate the help!